# Is there a robust estimator of the tail mean that is better than the sample tail mean?

Tags: robust, conditional-expectation, pareto-distribution, fat-tails

Suppose there is a large but finite population with values drawn from some heavily skewed distributional family with finite mean. I am supplied exogenously with the value of the 95th percentile, `q`. I now draw a conditionally random sample of members of the population with values greater than `q`. I wish to use this sample to estimate the mean of the tail `x > q` in the larger population.

My starting estimator is the mean for my sample, `X`.

Is there another unbiased estimator of the `x | x > q` tail mean that has a lower variance than X? Is there a minimum-varience estimator of the tail mean, given this sample drawn from the tail?
I have also posted a related question about improving a tail-mean estimate using  exogenously supplied information on extremal values for the population, [here:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325774/can-you-improve-an-estimate-of-the-right-tail-mean-with-extreme-order-statistics)

If it is helpful, the distribution in question is Pareto-like, but with a less heavy tail (but still heavier than a lognormal), as you might see with a generalized Pareto, a Burr XII/Singh–Maddala, or a Stoppa distribution. Do note that I am asking about the tail mean, not the tail index.

Comment: Surely if you know the distribution/ are willing to assume one, then estimating the distribution parameters e.g. by maximum likelihood and calculating the quantity of interest on that basis must be a serious option?

Comment: This issue really hinges on whether you are confident about confining the distribution to a parameterised subclass of possible distributions.  If you are using a parametric family, and you're confident of this form, then I agree with Bjorn - you can use all the data to estimate the parameters and then obtain the tail mean from that.  However, if you're not confident enough to constrain your problem you will be looking at a non-parametric analysis, and in that case you're a bit more restricted.

Comment: When I think of trying to take the mean of the tail of a variable that may not have a finite variance, I lose confidence that I can rely on my usual bag of tricks. Can you just assume that the good properties of ML parameter estimates will flow through to a tail mean in this setting?

Comment: If the the variance is infinite, I suspect that the mean is undefined.